# htaccess rewrite condition that uses regex

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm a noob when it comes to regex. What I'm trying to accomplish is:

`https://www.example.com/shop/product-floating-front-rotor-kit/`

should redirect to

`https://www.example.com/shop/product-matching-front-rotor/`

*product* should be the name of the product, I have to do this for multiple products.

**Edit:** This is what I have so far, am I even close?

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/shop/([a-z]+)-floating-front-rotor-kit/ ^/shop/$1-matching-front-rotor/
```

Comment: Like I said I'm a noob so I don't even know where to begin.

Comment: This is what I have so far, am I even close? RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule  ^/shop/([a-z]+)-floating-front-rotor-kit/  ^/shop/$1-matching-front-rotor/

Comment: Please edit your question to add the additional information. Information can get lost in unformatted code in comments. You appear to be close. Is `product` just a single word?

Comment: Edited my question and no, product may be more than one word separated by dashes. For example /shop/product-with-multiple-words-floating-front-rotor-kit/. The -floating-rotor-kit/ is what remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/shop/([a-z]+)-floating-front-rotor-kit/ ^/shop/$1-matching-front-rotor/
> ```

This is close, except that...

- In `.htaccess` the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* (first argument) does not start with a slash.
- The *substitution* string has an erroneous `^` prefix. This should be an "ordinary" string, not a regex.
- `[a-z]` does not match hyphens/dashes, which you state could occur in a product name.
- You have not included an end-of-string anchor (`$`) on the end of the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so any trailing string will be successful and discarded. (Is that the intention?)
- This is an internal "rewrite", not a "redirect" as stated. You need to include the `R` flag. (An internal rewrite is unlikely to work here, since the target URL requires further rewriting.)

Try the following instead. This should go at the top of the `.htaccess` file, immediately after the `RewriteEngine` directive.

```
RewriteRule ^shop/([a-z-]+)-floating-front-rotor-kit/$ /shop/$1-matching-front-rotor/ [R=302,L]
```

This is a 302 (temporary) redirect.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. If I wanted to make this a permanent rewrite should I change R=302 to R=301?

Comment: @krskaggs13 Yes, change to `R=301` for a permanent redirect. Note that it is preferable to test first with a 302 since 301s are cached persistently by the browser and can make testing problematic.